# Python: Remove value from dictionary and multiply remaining two

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I'm working with a large CSV file where each row includes the date and two values. I'm trying to set up a dictionary with the date as the key for the two values. I then need to multiply the two values of each key and record the answer. I have 3000 rows in the file.

Sample:
[image: Sample CSV File]

So far I have the date set as the key for each pair of values however it's also reusing the date as a third value for each key set, is there a way to remove this?

Once I've removed this, is there a way to multiply the values by eachother in each key set?

This is my code so far:

```
main_file = "newnoblanks.csv"
import csv
import collections
import pprint

with open(main_file) as fp:
    root = csv.reader(fp, delimiter=',')
    result = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for row in root:
        date = row[0].split(",")[0]
        result[date].append(row)

print ("Result:-")
pprint.pprint(result)
```

This is my output:

[image: Output]

Comment: Maybe you want: `result[date].append(list(map(float, row[1:])))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you even need to use a defaultdict here, just assign the whole row (minus the date) to the key of the dict. You should just be able to do

```
with open(main_file) as fp:
    root = csv.reader(fp, delimiter=',')
    result = dict()
    for row in root:
        date = row[0].split(",")[0]
        result[date] = row[1:]
```

If you want to get the product of the two values, you could do something like

```
for key in result:
    result[key] = reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, result[key])
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this has been answered, but feel there is an alternative worth considering:

```
import csv
from pprint import pprint
with open('newnoblanks.csv') as fp:
    root = csv.reader(fp)
    result = dict((date, float(a) * float(b)) for date, a, b in root)
    pprint(result)
```

With the following data file:

```
19/08/2004,49.8458,44994500
20/08/2004,53.80505,23005800
23/08/2004,54.34653,18393200
```

The output is:

```
{'19/08/2004': 2242786848.1,
 '20/08/2004': 1237828219.29,
 '23/08/2004': 999606595.5960001}
```